# Creating a self-contained JavaScript  "slider"

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

At the risk of showing the world what a novice I am, here goes:

I'm working on a site with a fluid (100%) width layout. On a particular page, I'd like to have a slider (although I guess it's really more of a fader) with slides containing text and HTML so they look like one more part of the page, but when a user clicks on a particular word or image on one slide, that will skip to another designated slide. Here's a graphic which hopefully explains what I'm going for:

[image]

http://marcatectura.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Slider-graphic.jpg

I've been messing around with a JSfiddle for days, but just can't seem to achieve the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/yxPQV/50/

Any help from the far more experienced folks on stackoverflow would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code based on the Coda Slider at http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/ is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PV7jA/9/

Comment: PitaJ that looks great however instead of clicking anywhere on a slide to advance, I'd like to designate only specific words or images within the slide area to skip to another slide. For example, on Slide 2 in your fiddle, clicking on "SLIDE 3" would skip to slide three and "SLIDE 4" would go to slide 4, but clicking elsewhere on slide 2 wouldn't necessarily do anything.

Comment: hmmm might be something I'm missing but when I open the fiddle it looks like the whole slide is still clickable and the SLIDE 3, SLIDE 4 etc areas don't seem to target their respective slides-but I appreciate your help, keep the expertise coming!

Comment: @Marcatectura - Does it work now? You should notice a semi-transparent arrow on each side. And if mine won't work, use this one: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/